# Output string after sring.split("").map breaks into pieces on small screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

With great help from @pratik-wadekar I have the following working text animation.
Now my problem is that when I test it on different screen sizes/mobile the animated word `plants` breaks into pieces. For example PLA and in the next line NTS. How can I avoid this? So it always keeps as one full word.

First I tried to add `\xC2\xA0 – non-breaking space or &nbsp;` before and after the word but this doesnt help. The CSS `word-wrap` property allows long words to be able to break but unfortunately for the reverse case to make a word unbreakable there is no option.

It seems that the CSS `word-break: "keep-all` property is what I need but when I apply it, it still breaks into pieces on smaller screens.

The [Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-mclaren-qytt3q?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1271)

And `App.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";

const AnimatedTypography = styled(Typography)`
 & {
   position: relative;
   -webkit-box-reflect: below -20px linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
   font-size: 60px;
 }

 & span {
   color: #fbbf2c;
   font-family: "Alfa Slab One", sans-serif;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   animation: waviy 1s infinite;
   animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
 }

 @keyframes waviy {
   0%,
   40%,
   100% {
     transform: translateY(0);
   }
   20% {
     transform: translateY(-20px);
   }
 }
`;

interface Styles extends React.CSSProperties {
 "--i": number;
}

function App() {
 const string = "plants";
 return (
   <Typography variant={"h3"} fontWeight={"bold"}>
     All Your
     <AnimatedTypography>
       {string.split("").map((char, idx) => {
         const styles: Styles = {
           "--i": idx + 1
         };
         return (
           <span key={`${char}-${idx}`} style={styles}>
             {char}
           </span>
         );
       })}
     </AnimatedTypography>
     in One Place
   </Typography>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. I had to make the animation as own component and add the `<AnimatedTypography>` the `component={"span"}` type and `white-space: nowrap`.
Additionally to my `const AnimatedTypography = styled(Typography)` I had to cast the resulting component with `as typeof Typograph`y so Typescript does not throws errors.
See here: [Complications with the component prop](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/typescript/#usage-of-component-prop)

Then importing the component and addind into the Typography component between my text. Now the layout of my text is preserved and the animation does not split into single characters.

Answer (score 0):

Every single character is a separate `<span>`, so it's not parsed as a single word. One solution would be to simply make the parent a `flex` container:

```
<AnimatedTypography style={{display:"flex"}}>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-sea-4o7498

Comment: When you say every single character is a separate span. So in order to get it behave like a single word I need to parse it as single word?